# What is the advantage to installing nvm from Git instead of curl or wget?

Tags: node.js, curl, npm, wget, nvm

You can install nvm using

curl: `curl -o-  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash`

wget: `wget -qO-  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash`

or Git: `git clone https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm`

In [one article](https://blog.helpmonks.com/switching-brew-nvm-node-install/) the user said "`I like to always grab the git one if possible`"

**What I Want To Know:**

1. Is there any difference between installing nvm either of these three different ways?
2. Why might a user prefer to do it with Git, as the author of the article stated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `githubusercontent.com` you have to be specific about the version you're trying to download, which is somewhat cumbersome. Furthermore, it doesn't guarantee that you're pulling the latest one.

While cloning the git itself should guarantee that you're pulling the master branch, which in a normal git workflow, should always be up to date after new version being released.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about githubusercontent.com. Do you mean that with the wgete and curl approaches, you have to specify the version of nvm, whereas with the git approach, it automatically gets the latest version?

Comment: `curl` and `wget` are just a shell command to make an http request. In this case, the http address is the `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/` which serves the raw files from git repositories.

by default, `git clone` command will download the source from the master branch which in normal situation should be the latest version.

Comment: I'm talking about git projects in general here. Mostly, big players rely on CI/CD (automated build system) for their projects. But not all projects are using them. Thus, the latest version are not guaranteed to be automatically merged into the master branch. In that case, the above statement doesn't apply.

Comment: That answers my question perfectly, thank you.